# Fire update progress within jQuery Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

How can I show update progress while jquery ajax call is fetching data?

Comment: That depends on what "update progress" is. You could simply show an indeterminate progress bar (or spinner) while the request is happening, however showing a meaningful progress bar would require the server telling the client where it is in the process. That could be done with either long polling or sockets.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Zend framework permit to update your UI for example http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.progressbar.introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
          url :
          type : 

          beforeSend : function() {

             //Show some processing div
               $('#loader').show();
          },
          success : function() {
               /// Your code
          },

          complete : function() {
               //Hide the processing div
               $('#loader').hide();
          }
      });
```

You can create a div which you want to show it while processing.

You can show the div in the `beforeSend` function which gets called just before the request.
Hide it in the `complete` function which is called once the request is completed.